# How do you make a connection to Power BI through an application's API

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have an Azure SQL Database and have made a direct connection from Power BI to it. The problem is that to successfully import the data, I had to give direct access to the data through the database firewall which I cannot allow.

Is there a way to use my application's API as the data source for Power BI rather than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

Most of the tools that work on representing/caching/plotting data work with industry-standard adapters (sql, mongo, hadoop, etc.). There are a varieties of reasons for that.

Some simpler tools might exist where you can push data for reprsentation but that kills the power of things like PowerBI, Periscope or ChartIO.

Now, why not grant PowerBI access to your database?

Comment: The reason I cannot allow access to the database is that it contains customers' confidential data. The API uses OAuth to authenticate users and give role based access to data.

Comment: Just integrate your oauth2 or your active directory to register access with rights / scopes so people only have access to their own data. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-power-bi-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

One option I would suggest is that you could make a small piece of code that gets the necessary data (either through your API or directly from DB) and pushes it to Power BI through their REST API.

Comment: I've tried this, thanks, but as @muichkine said, you end up with no relationships between the tables and this takes all the power out of Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

You can query an API via PowerBI. Please see my answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685463/how-to-connect-my-web-api-wtih-power-bi-reports/36821858#36821858).

If you can, I would recommend using [OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api), as PowerBi plays well with it.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-tutorial-analyzing-sales-data-from-excel-and-an-odata-feed/