# how to connect my web api wtih Power BI Reports?

Tags: powerbi

I have a web API to deliver required data sources for my reports. How can I connect my web API with Power BI. I gone through Rest API. But I am missing the complete flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Home > Edit Queries > Advance Editor. Here is some Power Query code to query issue a GET request to an API endpoint.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://mywebapi"))
in
    Source
```

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260892.aspx

and here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/03/26/working-with-web-services-in-power-query/