# how to use Power Bi Microsoft Without the use of Azure Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, report, local, powerbi

I am just getting started Power Bi

And I have in mind for Local use And Not Use Azure Services

And report output in software that is written By Asp.Net Mvc

I thank you for your answer , if possible , if  introduced similar project

Answer (score 0):

I believe, there is no way to do that without Azure at all - local hosting is in the development. Microsoft has the corresponding implementation called PowerBI Embedded to implement what you want:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/

Answer (score 0):

You can use other data sources like JSON, XML, CSV, or API's with custom scripts to achieve the same without using Azure services.

Ref: [how to connect my web api wtih Power BI Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685463/how-to-connect-my-web-api-wtih-power-bi-reports)