# Can we create Power BI Embedded dashboards/reports in web applications without Microsoft Azure?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have been using SSRS and .Net framework to create reports for my applications.
Now I want to generate reports and create dashboards using Power BI Embedded. But the documentation/demos for Power BI always say that we need to create Power BI services on Azure. I wonder if there was any way to do this without Azure.

I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086815/how-to-use-power-bi-microsoft-without-the-use-of-azure-services)
but the answers there have no approvals/comments,please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Power BI Report Server. It is a super-set of SSRS, which can host Power BI reports. For more information you can start from these articles:

- [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/)
- [What is Power BI Report Server?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/get-started)
- [Quickstart: Embed a Power BI Report Server report using an iFrame in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed)

Essentially, embedding reports with Power BI Report Server is performed by adding "rs:embed=true" parameter to the report's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Embedding for your Organization in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding